# "Type" Reserved keyword in salesforce

Tags: apex

Can anyone please provide some detailed description about How to use the "Type" reserved keyword of salesforce ?

Comment: The [Type Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm) can be used for limited reflection and dynamic instantiation... the docs are great.

Comment: @user320 You should post that as the answer. That is essentially what this user is looking for. You may want to add a bit more detail, but as you noted, Salesforce has great documentation.

Comment: Agreed.  The question is not very detailed or specific, so pointing them to documentation with a link seems adequate in this case.

Comment: Can you please try to use correct tags related to the subject of your question ? This will help you get answers quicker! Also: trying to shape your question around specific problems makes it easier to provide answers. Questions that are too broad or unclear do get closed.

Comment: Thanks All. Actually I saw use of this into an apex class and tried to find out the exact meaning but didn't get anything. So I posted this question here. 

@user320 thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The System.Type class represents a reference to a class. There are two basic purposes for using System.Type.

### Dynamically Accessing Classes

In [this question's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24139/perform-basic-math-operation-add-sub-multi-div-after-selecting-a-operation-fro), I show how you can dynamically select a function to invoke by calling one of four operations from a map. First, you create an interface or abstract class, then you create subclasses/implementations, followed by mapping them out somehow, and finally invoking them through the common interface or parent class methods.

Here's the controller that uses the interface-style method:

```
public class calculatorController {
    interface operation {
        decimal execute(decimal op1, decimal op2);
    }
    class Add implements operation {
        public decimal execute(decimal op1, decimal op2) { return op1 + op2; }
    }
    class Subtract implements operation {
        public decimal execute(decimal op1, decimal op2) { return op1 - op2; }
    }
    class Multiply implements operation {
        public decimal execute(decimal op1, decimal op2) { return op1 * op2; }
    }
    class Divide implements operation {
        public decimal execute(decimal op1, decimal op2) { return op1 / op2; }
    }
    public selectoption[] getoperators() {
        return new SelectOption[] {
            new SelectOption('add', '+'),
            new SelectOption('sub', '-'),
            new SelectOption('mul', '*'),
            new SelectOption('div', '/')
        };
    }
    public decimal op1 { get; set; }
    public decimal op2 { get; set; }
    public string op { get; set; }
    public decimal result { get; set; }

    public void calculate() {
        map<string, type> ops = new map<string, type> {
            'add' => add.class,
            'sub' => subtract.class,
            'mul' => multiply.class,
            'div' => divide.class
        };
        try {
            operation o = (operation)ops.get(op).newinstance();
            result = o.execute(op1, op2);
        } catch(exception e) {
            result = null;
            apexpages.addmessages(e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Dynamic Code Injection

By using `Type.forName`, you can invoke logic that isn't included in the original package, perhaps as a detection routine for extensions, or as a facility for after-market classes that might be introduced by the installed organization.

I've only rarely seen this usage, but it could be used to provide a hook into trigger logic, or page logic, etc. For example, a managed package trigger might look like this:

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, after insert, before update, after update, before delete, after delete, after undelete) {
    try {
        ((CaseExtension)Type.forName(null, 'CaseTriggerExtension')).handleTrigger();
    } catch(TriggerException e) {
        // Handle exceptons thrown by third party code
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // Ignore other exceptions
    }
    // Perform your managed code here
}
```

In this case, the system tries to call a class named `CaseTriggerExtension` in the default namespace that conforms to a global interface named `CaseExtension`, which has a single method defined (`handleTrigger`). If there is no such class, or it doesn't conform to the interface, or some uncaught exception occurs, the trigger carries on with other logic. Conversely, there is a global exception class called `TriggerException` that extends `Exception`, and `CaseTriggerExtension` can throw a specific exception that can possibly interrupt or rollback the routine. Since it is a custom class, you could include a means to determine which records had the error, or return early to allow the system's automatic retry handler (if *allOrNone* is false) to restart the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

The `Type` class can be used for limited reflection and dynamic instantiation. [Check out the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm)